# Suggested Edit with no changes

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I reviewed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3038216) which as far as I can tell has no actual changes. I had [previously reviewed a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3038193) on the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643182/how-to-handle-error-in-codeigniter-framework-php), from the [same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1928157/imj4u), with the same comment but it actual had changes, which was approved.

Is something weird going on here or am I just being blind?

Comment: This should be an audit - anything but "too minor" would be a failure.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not an audit.

Comment: @Servy I know. I'm saying it should be.

Comment: @JanDvorak Audits should be clear cut.  When something looks like a bug (because it likely is) it's confusing.  Audits shouldn't be confusing.

Comment: most likely it's a concurrent edit - the exact same set of changes was done in by two people, of which one started later, finished sooner and had 2k+ rep.

Comment: @JanDvorak +1 since that sounds likely, but can we get a confirmation on that?  I'm *somewhat* sure when I've attempted a concurrent edit as a <2k user, I was not able to do so.

Comment: @BLaZuRE you need to start sooner and submit later than the other one.

Comment: @JanDvorak I actually tested this and sat on a question that would probably get edited (went to edit and idled at the text box).  I got this at the top of the page: **"This post has been edited 2 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit."**  I don't know if that applies to 2k+ rep users as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just tested this in the Tavern not long ago. These "no changes were made" edits occur when a user retags the question with a tag that gets remapped to a tag that was already on the question. The system accepts the edit as a new suggestion, even though the tag change results in the same set of tags that already existed, and thus the Diff doesn't see that anything has actually changed when displaying the suggestion.

I would classify this as a bug, because the suggested edit is essentially useless. No real change was made, it's confusing to reviewers, and most of all a complete waste of everyone's time. I've noticed these popping up more here on Meta from anonymous users trying to "comment" on the question not realizing that it won't ever show up anywhere. I really think that the suggested edit shouldn't be created until after it checks what the tags will actually be once remapped, and comparing against the existing tags.