# How can a user suggest an edit with no changes w.r.t. the original?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

On Aviation.SE I recently [rejected an edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29177) that was not an edit at all, it neither removed or added any character to the tag wiki excerpt that it wanted to edit.

Is this a know bug?

I had a look to a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198959/376358), but that focuses on edits on normal posts, and the answer does as well, and I don't see how they would apply to this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see the [SEDE query for that edit](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/771848), you will see that there is a line end added to the except. This caused the edit to take affect (and be submitted as suggested edit).

I guess this edit was not intentional, OP just wanted to change the tag wiki instead.

CSV export of the SEDE query for the related lines:

```
Text                                          Length
----------------------------------------------------
"Questions relating to aviation in Pakistan.","43"
"Questions relating to aviation in Pakistan.
"                                            ,"45"
```

An easy fix would be to trim the input for start and end spaces. You could post a feature request for that.

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304725/376358) thank you. I am still a bit surprised about the fact that 2 chars were enough, but I guess the answer is already somewhere out there.