# Can leading/trailing whitespace be trimmed from suggested edit?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

This is based on [the feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304724/376358) I got on my previous question.

Apparently an edit (shorter than the expected 6 chars) to a tag wiki excerpt was suggested on Aviation.SE. The edit consisted only of one return character and one space, both at the end of the excerpt.

Would it be possible to trim any leading/trailing whitespaces from any suggested edit before checking if the edit is a valid one and allow it to go in the review queue?

Comment: It doesn't seem useful indeed to have spaces before or after *any* post, so ban them altogether.

Comment: (You might want to update this post to include all other post types, like questions and answers. Seems to be the same there.)

Comment: @PatrickHofman updated, but I was under the impression that questions and answers are safeguarded by the 6 char limit, aren't they?

Comment: What about 6 line ends then?

Comment: It seems so, but not if you delete one space character: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29252. I needed to delete one space and multiple line ends to make this work.